# Invalid use of group function. But not using group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join a table into forcing only to show the results of voucherroll that have more than 0 not printed vouchers.
But now I am getting the message that i am using a group function wrong. However, I think I'm not using group by at all.
Any ideas?

```
SELECT * 
FROM voucherroll INNER JOIN voucher ON voucherroll.id = voucher.id_voucherroll
WHERE voucher.printed = 0
AND Count(voucher.id > 0)
```

An updated explanation:
There are multiple rolls, with multiple vouchers.
if vouchers are printed, they are not supposed to be shown.
I want every roll, where the not printed vouchers are more than 0

Comment: Count() is a grouping function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `count()` and it doesn't belong in `where`.

Perhaps this is your intention?

```
SELECT *
FROM voucherroll INNER JOIN
     voucher
     ON voucherroll.id = voucher.id_voucherroll
WHERE voucher.printed = 0 AND voucher.id IS NOT NULL;
```

It would be unusual, though, for something called `id` to take on `NULL` values.

EDIT:

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT vr.*
FROM voucherroll vr
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM voucher v
              WHERE vr.id = v.id_voucherroll and
                    v.printed = 0
             )
```

If you want more than 1, then use the less efficient:

```
SELECT vr.*
FROM voucherroll vr
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM voucher v
       WHERE vr.id = v.id_voucherroll and
             v.printed = 0
      ) > 1;
```

Comment: no, i want all rolls where the number of not printed(hence the printed=0) vouchers is more than one

Comment: @MichelKok . . . Your question says "0" not "1", both in the text and in the sample query.

Comment: seems that what i thought i need, was not exactly how i needed it. But in this case both work so thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subquery to count as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM voucherroll
INNER JOIN voucher ON voucherroll.id = voucher.id_voucherroll
WHERE voucher.printed = 0
AND (select count(v.id)
     from voucher v
     where voucherroll.id = v.id_voucherroll ) > 0
```

You can't use `count` in `where` clause. It is possible in `having` clause, but you need to use `group by`.